# How to access application data on an iOS 8 device from terminal?

Tags: ios, shell, ios8, filesystems, archive

We are running some tests on our iOS app.  The app generates a log file in Library/Caches/Logs/.  On an iOS 7 device, we could create an archive of the app, which would contain the app data, and copy the archive to our local machine from the device.  Using the `ideviceinstaller` utility from `libimobiledevice` (http://www.libimobiledevice.org/), we could then unzip the archive and extract the log file:

```
# Archive the app and copy to our local machine
ideviceinstaller --udid  $DEVICE_ID --archive ${BUNDLE_ID} -o copy=.

# Unzip the archive and redirect the log file to a file in our current directory
unzip -p ${BUNDLE_ID}.ipa "$(unzip -l ${BUNDLE_ID}.ipa | grep -o "Container/Library/Caches/Logs/${LOG_FILE_NAME}")" > ./${LOG_FILE_NAME}
```

Unfortunately this no longer seems to work on an iOS 8 device, because of changes to where an app's data is stored in the file system.  In particular, apparently app data is no longer included in the app archive: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html

We need a way to access this log file on the device, and copy it to our local machine, via a shell script.  I'm pretty new to iOS development, so I'm sort of stumped as to how I might do this or whether it's still possible in iOS 8.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if anything needs clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a utility called `ifuse` (https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) which lets me mount the sandboxed root folder of the app and copy the file to my local machine:

```
# E.g. ifuse --container com.blah.yourappname <mountpoint>
ifuse --container ${BUNDLE_ID} ~/mnt

# I found I needed to sleep for a few seconds before trying to access
# the filesystem, otherwise I'd get "Device not configured" errors...
sleep 5 

cp ~/mnt/Library/Caches/Logs/${LOG_FILE} ~
umount ~/mnt
```

Hope this helps someone else!